# Как собрать/смикшировать трек на аудиодорожке/таймлайне NAudio?

Tags: c#, аудио, wav, naudio, timeline

Всем привет!

Нужно собрать полноценную аудио дорожку.

Фоновая музыка, плюс короткие звуки (выстрелы, взрывы, крики).

Короткие звуки в строго точных по времени точках.

Спасибо за ответы и ссылки!

Псевдокод вместо тысячи слов.

```
Timeline tl = new Timeline(5.0f); // 5 seconds track lenght
tl.Add(0.0f, "Ambient.wav"); // music from start
tl.Add(0.9f, "Blast.wav");
tl.Add(2.33f, "Jump.wav");
tl.Export("output.wav");
```

Answer (score 0):

Покурил маны, решил вопрос таким образом. Хотя и ожидал более "дорожечную" концепцию монтажа.

```
var ambient = new AudioFileReader("Ambient.mp3");
var blast = new AudioFileReader("Blast.mp3");

var off = new OffsetSampleProvider(blast);
off.DelayBy = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

var mixer = new MixingSampleProvider(new[] { ambient });
mixer.AddMixerInput(off);

WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16("Output.wav", mixer);
```